# How to read NSData into clientside made in java

Tags: java, ios, server, gcdasyncsocket

I create an iOS server using GCDAsyncSocket and Client is created using Java language. When I sent data in form of NSDAta it can be read by SocketTester(application for testing client connection) but it cannot be completely read at java end .

```
static void   recorderServerClient() throws  IOException{
    int port =9892;
        clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", port);
        System.out.print("Connected to localhost"+port);

        while (true){
        InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
         catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }/*fetch data with help of output stream and write it with help of PrintWriter */
      PrintWriter printWriterObj = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); 
          printWriterObj.println();
            printWriterObj.flush();
           /*created an array for now static and assign some memory */              byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
            int read;
            while((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                String output = new String(buffer, 0, read);
               System.out.print(output);
                System.out.flush();
            }
        }
        */
```

}

I want to get data length sent through ios server.and create buffer accordingly.Can any one help me out?

Comment: what issues are you seeing? Seems your missing Socket.accept() call?

Comment: I cannot able to read the data length by readInt method of java .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using

```
public static byte[] readChunkedData(final InputStream stream, final int size) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(stream);
        din.readFully(buffer);
        return buffer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 2100);
        System.out.println("Connected");

        DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream  out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("opened OutputStreams");

        System.out.println(readResponse(ins));
        Thread.sleep(100);
        out.write("ss 1\n".getBytes());//send command
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("sent command");
        Thread.sleep(3000);//important to wait for the server to response
        System.out.println(readResponse(ins));
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("Connection to the server closed");
    }

    private static String readResponse(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];//1k
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (in.available() > 0) {//server is waiting for client once it sent all data
            int pos  = in.read(buf);
            String s = new String(buf, 0, pos);
            sb.append(s);
            //System.out.println("reading data..." + pos + " s>>>" + s.getBytes() + "available?" +  ins.available());
            //System.out.print(pos + " ? " + (char) pos);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry this code does not work in my case.It just hang my system .I just want an client who can connect to the port and read data completely

Comment: As I said its a demo. When you said it hangs your system. What do you mean? How do you connect to the server socket? This is how you test this demo. Run the program and it will say "Server started and is listen on 9892". Then open up another terminal and type "telnet localhost 9892". Type a number to start with then it will echo what you typed. It should be obvious if you understand the code.

Comment: I have written  server in iOS using GCDSyncSocket Class. Only client part has to be done on java end. After checking your code, it does not work for me. and it simply hang my system 3 times. No cursor movement .Every running application just hangs.

Comment: Sorry my code is also a server socket...let me create the client code but then you can use Telnet to communicate right? So how does the client talk to the server socket? After connected what need to be sent?

Comment: I need to sent NSData which holds JSON Strings as well total number of length in form of (length of actual string+actual string).and on Java client side  I need to just read that complete data

Comment: I have updated the code. I have tested this against a server socket which waits for command to be entered before responding. Take note of 1) the wait - give server a chance to reply 2) Inputsteam.avaliable() - the server send some data and wait for the response. I was looking for -1 which is EOF which the server never sent.

Comment: The sleeps are literally a waste of time. The line terminator in Telnet is defined as `\r\n`, not `\n`. `InputStream.available()` is not a test for end of message or end of stream. Answer is complete rubbish. If this is not intended as an answer it should not have been posted as an answer.